# Update function Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want this function, if the status of **progress** so that it changes on the **done** exactly at those IDs where the status is for the conditions, at the moment I get an error and secondly, if it worked without errors, then it would change everything, but I need if progress is finished and if you don’t, then on progress

I selected three records through the form using a checkbox ...
in the function, I want that if the status of the record from database is "done", then it should change to "progress", if the status is "progress" in the record, then it should be changed to "done". Now I click on "submit_tag" and I get an error and in any case this code will not work the way I want it, I want everything to be conditional.

I am completely in ruby, help please, maybe the problem is in the syntax

```
no implicit conversion from nil to integer


 def update_me
      @iteam = Iteam.find(params[:id])
      if @iteam[params[:status]] == 'progress' 
        Iteam.where(params[:id]).update_all(status: 'DONE')
      else
        Iteam.where(params[:id]).update_all(status: 'progress')
      end 
 end
```

index view

```
<%= form_tag update_me_iteams_path, :method =>'put' do %>


    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <% @iteams.each do |iteam| %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= iteam.id %></td>
        <td><%= iteam.title %></td>
        <td><%= iteam.text %></td>
        <td><%= iteam.status %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', iteam_path(iteam) %></td>
        
        <td>
            <%= check_box_tag "id[]", iteam.id %>
            

        </td>

        </tr>
    <% end %>

    
    </table>
    
    <%= submit_tag "Edit Checked" %> 

  <% end %>
```

Comment: Please update the description. It's very difficult to understand what you want.

Comment: please check , i update

Comment: Update with the request params, they way you see them in the development.log

Answer (score 0):

Please Use following to find with id:
Iteam.where(id: params[:id])
or you can use the following
Iteam.find(params[:id])

Comment: to be honest, I didn't understand your idea a little

Comment: I need the status to change depending on the condition

Comment: Use Iteam.where(id: params[:id]).update_all(status: 'DONE') instead of Iteam.where(params[:id]).update_all(status: 'DONE')